# Net::HTTP::Server fails when reading a file

Tags: ruby, httpserver

I'm trying to write a very simple HTTP server that returns the next 500 lines of a file on each request. If I try to read a file, the server fails.

This is my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'net/http/server'
require 'pp'

file = File.foreach("data/all.txt").each_slice(500)

headers = {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}
Net::HTTP::Server.run(:port => 2000) do |request, stream|
    [200, headers, file.next]
end
```

If I make a request, I get the first 500 lines from the file, but I get this on the console:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/generator.rb:132:in`call'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/generator.rb:132:in`next'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/generator.rb:190:in`next' ./urlServer.rb:12
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-http-server-0.2.2/lib/net/http/server/daemon.rb:122:in`call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-http-server-0.2.2/lib/net/http/server/daemon.rb:122:in`serve'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/gserver.rb:211:in`start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/gserver.rb:208:in`initialize'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/gserver.rb:208:in`new'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/gserver.rb:208:in`start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/gserver.rb:198:in`initialize'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/gserver.rb:198:in`new'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/gserver.rb:198:in`start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-http-server-0.2.2/lib/net/http/server/server.rb:42:in`run' ./urlServer.rb:11
```

All further requests fail.

How do I fix this program?

Comment: Is there more of this stack trace?  Seems like it's missing a root error.

Comment: How long is the file?

Comment: For some reason, file.next is returning a nil and it's trying to perform an operation to serve it(but can't)

Comment: @NickVeys That is all I get on the console. It doesn't mention an error anywhere.

Comment: @VodkaTonic The file is 147MB. About 2.9 million lines.

Comment: @VodkaTonic file.next never returns on the second request. That is what's failing.

Comment: Okay so this is not the way to go. Are you just trying to parse through and serve the file? I just ran your program and used "readlines.each_slice(500);" where you have file.next(and had a file.open earlier) and worked. "each_slice" is looking for an array and foreach is looking for a block to run on each object back from ruby.

Answer (score 1):

When the Enumerator in the `file` variable reaches then end, the `next` method will raise a `StopIteration` exception, but you are not rescuing it so that is likely the issue here.

You probably want to wrap it in a begin-rescue block, e.g.:

```
Net::HTTP::Server.run(:port => 2000) do |request, stream|
  begin
    body = file.next
  rescue StopIteration
    body = []
  end

  [200, headers, body]
end
```

Comment: Its throwing a "continuation called across threads" exception on the second call to file.next.